# Como crear correctamente botones para productos y categorías sin saber cuántos vas a crear (desde una lista)

Tags: java, java-swing, jbutton

A ver si consigo explicarme:
Estoy formandome en JAVA, y para practicar me he puesto a intentar hacer algo como los programas que usan en la hostelería para gestionar productos, ventas, etc.

Al crear la pantalla desde la que se vende, que deberían de salir las categorias, subcategoorias y productos, hice un bucle que recorre la lista de productos y categorias y crea e imprime como botones lo que corresponda. Al entrar en otra categoría, el proceso se repite y se crean e imprimen los botones correspondientes. El caso es que, digamos que si entro en la categoria BEBIDAS, vuelvo para GENERAL, y vuelvo a entrar en BEBIDAS y así hasta el infinito, estoy creando infinitos botones, porque no juego con por ejemplo el atributo setVisible para activarlos y desactivarlos según corresponda, sino que estoy creandolos en un bucle una y otra vez.

La primera pregunta es: Según mi profesor el colector de java se encarga de recolectar esos botones que dejo en el olvido. Es esto asi? Si lo es, tengo que llamar yo a Systemn.gc o lo hace de forma automatica?

En caso de no ser así, alguien podría iluminarme un poco con cómo debería hacerlo? Porque como no sé cuántos botones crearé (dependen directamente del número de productos y categorías que haya en ese momento) no se cómo gestionar el atributo setVisible sin saber la cantidad que voy a crear de antemano.
Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, aunque sea una pista de por dónde van las cosas. Muchas gracias.

```
private void dibujarProductos (ProductPane panel, int categoria) {
        removeAll();
        //System.gc();
        ArrayList<Categoria> categorias = Categoria.listaCategorias().stream().filter(x->x.getIDPadre()==categoria).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
       
        ArrayList<Producto> productos = Producto.listaProductos().stream().filter(x->x.getID_Categoria()==categoria).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        
        JButton botones;
        int indice = 0;
        int indiceX = 0;
        int indiceY = 0;
        for (int i = 0, y=0,x=0; i<categorias.size();i++,x++) {
            if (i%cantidadProductosAncho==0) {
                y=anchoBotones*i/cantidadProductosAncho;
                x=0;
            }
            indiceY=y;
            indice = i;
            indiceX=x;
            botones = new JButton(categorias.get(i).getNombre());
            botones.setBounds(x*anchoBotones,y,anchoBotones,anchoBotones);
            botones.setBackground(Color.white);
            JButton finalBotones = botones;
            int finalI = i;
            botones.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    dibujarProductos(panel, categorias.get(finalI).getID());

                }
            });
            panel.add(botones);
        }
        int desplazamiento=0;
        for (int i = indice, y=indiceY,x=indiceX+1; i<productos.size()+indice;i++,x++) {
            if (i%cantidadProductosAncho==0) {
                y=anchoBotones*i/cantidadProductosAncho;
                x=0;
            }
            indiceY=y;
            indiceX=x+1;
            desplazamiento=i;
            botones = new JButton(productos.get(i-indice).getNombre());
            botones.setBounds(x*anchoBotones,y,anchoBotones,anchoBotones);
            JButton finalBotones = botones;
            botones.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Producto añadido: " + finalBotones.getText());
                }
            });

            panel.add(botones);
        }
        if (categoria>1) {
          if (indiceX%cantidadProductosAncho==0&&desplazamiento!=0) {
                indiceY=indiceY+anchoBotones;
                indiceX=0;
            }
            botones = new JButton("General");
            botones.setBounds((indiceX)*anchoBotones,indiceY,anchoBotones,anchoBotones);
            botones.setBackground(Color.white);

            botones.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    dibujarProductos(panel, 1);
                }
            });

            panel.add(botones);
        }
        panel.updateUI();
 }
```

Comment: Efectivamente, el GC de java se encargará de "borrarlos" de memoria a no ser que guardes una referencia a ellos en la página que estás mostrando actualmente, entonces nunca los borrará por si los usas. Pero si lo que haces es mostrarlos en otra ventana, el GC sí que los limpiará. Por otro lado, dado que no vas a tener tantísimos botones siempre puedes guardarlos por ejemplo en un `Map<String, Map<String, JButton>>` y cuando cargues una pantalla buscas los elementos por ejemplo: `mapaBotones.get("vinos")` y recorres el mapa añadiendo todos sus botones. Así te evitas andar creándolos cada vez

Comment: El *garbage collector* se invoca de forma automática. *System.gc()* es solo una sugerencia para que se ejecute el *garbage collector*. Y no es obligatorio que el *garbage collector* libere en cada pasada todos los objetos no referenciados (eso se puede ajustar un poco jugando con los parámetros de la JVM).

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias por la respuesta. Me quedan un par de dudas...
por un lado, comentas: "a no ser que guardes una referencia a ellos en la página que estás mostrando actualmente". El JPanel en el que monto todo siempre es el mismo, solo que hago un removeAll() y updateUI entre un montaje y otro. Quiere decir esto que dejo de referenciarlos? o como es el mismo panel, la referencia queda ahí con lo que el GC no los elimina?

Comment: Por otro, había pensado en algo como dices de crear mapas de botones, pero, como realmente no se sabe cuantas categorías habrá ni cuantos productos dentro de cada una, no supe como gestionarlo. Le daré un par de vueltas a la cabeza a ver qué se me ocurre siguiendo esa linea. Muchas gracias